# iptables - how to drop protocols

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, protocols

I have the desktop-server Debian Jessie machine running for testing purposes just for 19 hours now. I have already set a few rules as you can see above. But I am not really into networking. So it needs some revision.

Here is my `iptables -L -v`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 1429 packets, 233K bytes)
 pkts bytes target   prot opt in     out   source     destination         
 1360 61482 DROP     all  --  any    any   anywhere   anywhere    ctstate INVALID
25079 2528K DROP     icmp --  any    any   anywhere   anywhere            
   15   480 DROP     igmp --  any    any   anywhere   anywhere            
14353 7379K ACCEPT   all  --  lo     any   anywhere   anywhere            
5848K 1157M ACCEPT   all  --  any    any   anywhere   anywhere    ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 1632 86441 ACCEPT   tcp  --  eth0   any   anywhere   anywhere    tcp dpt:8333
    9   472 ACCEPT   tcp  --  eth0   any   anywhere   anywhere    tcp dpt:33211
13801  804K ACCEPT   tcp  --  eth0   any   anywhere   anywhere    tcp dpt:56874
58386 5659K ACCEPT   udp  --  eth0   any   anywhere   anywhere    udp dpt:56874
    0     0 ACCEPT   tcp  --  eth0   any   anywhere   anywhere    tcp dpt:63547
    0     0 ACCEPT   tcp  --  eth0   any   anywhere  anywhere     tcp dpt:https
```

How can I drop all other incoming protocols than the ones I need, like HTTP(S), as the machine will serve mainly as a web server?

**When I run Etherape I see lots of protocols trying to connect through (or may have already penetrated) my firewall.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above iptables config will only let TCP and UDP packets get past the firewall (unless they came from loopback).  The default rule of the INPUT chain has been set to DROP, meaning that every packet that isn't explicitly ACCEPTed will be discarded.  There should be no weird packets from loopback, so only TCP/UDP packets are allowed in.

There is one major thing about protocols which should be cleared up: Network communication happens on [many (actually seven) layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and each layer has it's own set of protocols.  E.g., there are fundamental differences between the purpose of transport layer protocols (like TCP and UDP) and application layer protocols (like SMB).  The scope of iptables is limited to the transport layer and below.  Analysing packets for their application layer protocols requires deep packet inspection and is computationally much more expensive.

One should also be careful not to confuse protocols and service names.  Popular services have been [assigned to specific ports](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers).  FTP services are typically available on port 21, while a web server will listen on port 80.  This *implies* that the protocol in use will usually be FTP for traffic on port 21 and HTTP on port 80.  However, traffic on any such port is in no way required to use the protocol associated with that service.  Traffic on port 80 might as well be SSH or complete gibberish.